# How to delete text from Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how do u delete text inside the Tkinter. The text is circled in red.

My code is as below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import win32com.client

root = Tk()
root.title('PM1 Digital Checklist')
root.geometry("400x400")

def open_excel():
    if combo.get() == 'PPM8001':
        myLabel = Label(root, text="Prime Mover Number Selected is:").pack()
        myLabel = Label(root, text=combo.get()).pack()
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        file = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"/path/to/PPM8001.xlsx")

    if combo.get() == 'PPM8002':
        myLabel = Label(root, text="Prime Mover Number Selected is:").pack()
        myLabel = Label(root, text=combo.get()).pack()
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        file = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"/path/to/PPM8002.xlsx")

    if combo.get() == 'PPM8003':
        myLabel = Label(root, text="Prime Mover Number Selected is:").pack()
        myLabel = Label(root, text=combo.get()).pack()
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        file = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"/path/to/PPM8003.xlsx")

options = ['PPM8001','PPM8002','PPM8003']

v = list(options)

combo = Combobox(root, values = v, width =40)
combo.set("Select which Prime Mover number")
combo.pack()

button = Button(root, text = "Select", command = open_excel).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The image is here:

[image]

Comment: Mind sharing, what you have tried in form of a code snippet?

Comment: Please provide some code for something you've tried and hasn't woked.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to fix:

1. use

```
myLabel = Label(root, text="Prime Mover Number Selected is:")
myLabel.pack()
```

To actually put a Label instance into a variable

2. use

```
myLabel.destroy()
```

To get rid of it.

Hope that's helpful!